# PHP Regex, get multiple value with preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I have this text string:

```
$text="::tower_unit::7::/tower_unit::<br/>::tower_unit::8::/tower_unit::<br/>::tower_unit::9::/tower_unit::";
```

Now I want to get the value of 7,8, and 9
how to do that in preg_match_all ?

I've tried this:

```
$pattern="/::tower_unit::(.*)::\/tower_unit::/i";
preg_match($pattern,$text,$matches);

print_r($matches);
```

but it still all wrong...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to escape the slash in your pattern. Since your pattern includes slashes, it's easier to use a different regex delimiter, as suggested in the comments:

```
$pattern="@::tower_unit::(\d+)::/tower_unit::@"; 
preg_match_all($pattern,$text,$matches);
```

I also converted `(.*)` to `(\d+)`, which is better if the token you're looking for will always be a number. Plus, you might want to lose the `i` modifier if the text is always lower cased.

Comment: I never really understood why people insist on using `/` as the start/end character, especially when it's used in the pattern itself.

Comment: @Mark: If you come from a JavaScript or Ruby background (where the slash is the only possible delimiter), you might not expect that you can freely choose your delimiter in PHP/Perl.

Comment: @Mark I'm guessing most don't know you can use a different character, as almost all the popular PHP examples for some reason use `/`

Comment: @Mark i agree with Dor... i never realize i can use different character.. in my 7 years using php, i just realize it.. how ironic..

Comment: @Viktor: Well I'm glad I taught you something new then ;) It can be quite handy sometimes. URLs come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is "greedy".
Use the following one

```
$pattern="#::tower_unit::(.*?)::/tower_unit::#i";
```

or

```
$pattern="#::tower_unit::(.*)::/tower_unit::#iU";
```

and, if you wish, \d+ instead of .*? or .*

the function should be preg_match_all

Comment: btw, could you give reference what 'U' means in the last character of pattern... what possible between i and U

Comment: @Viktor        U means "ungreedy", without it .* will get everything until the last match. Without modificator U .*? can be used. i means "case-insensitive", so [a-z] is the same as [a-zA-Z] or any words in regexp will not depend on the case. Read here http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php